# Why would you ever GRANT special permissions on a SEQUENCE?

Tags: postgresql, sql-grant

What would be a good use case for restricting permissions on a SEQUENCE in a database?

Usually, when I GRANT permissions on a TABLE, I also GRANT the same permissions on the SEQUENCES. It seems like a redundant step, so is there a good use case for when SEQUENCE permissions differ from TABLE permissions?

Answer (score 2):

I can see 3 reasons.

- Not all sequences are attached to a table, so it makes sense to allow access to them separately.
  For instance, an application that sending messages to a server may need a unique identifier for all messages, in which case a DB sequence is a convenient way to generate ids that will be unique across all clients.
- Unlike tables, regular users are very rarely granted all privileges on a sequence when they are on a table and they are different anyway (respectively `SELECT USAGE UPDATE` and `SELECT INSERT UPDATE DELETE TRUNCATE REFERENCES TRIGGER`). That would create a mess to grant all privileges on sequences. The right approach is to only grant `USAGE` on sequences.
  You can probably imagine the risk of letting **anyone** reset a sequence to 1 when the said sequence is used to generate primary key values on a table.
  In that sense, privilege on sequences really need to be managed separately.
- The standard behavior for all objects in a database and more generally for everything related to security, is that you have to **explicitly** grant privileges on an object before anybody can use it.
  The two bulletpoints above merely explain why privileges must be specific to sequences but here is a more general consideration about why privileges are never granted by default.